# Called method not responding - Xcode 4 / objective-C c

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, ipad

I've got a problem with calling methods in external files which I have imported into my project. The methods are for some reason not being called, even though the project compiles ok. And there is no error message/ output in the console.

Can someone help?? Here's the full problem:

(1) I downloaded the Flickr API (4 files) written [by the author of this tutorial](http://www.raywenderlich.com/22324/beginning-uicollectionview-in-ios-6-part-12) and drag&dropped into the Xcode file manager, specifying to copy and link the 4 files with my project.

```
* Flickr.h
* Flickr.m
* FlickrPhoto.h
* FlickrPhoto.m
```

(2) In the main view controller, I first import the external files

```
#import "Flickr.h"
#import "FlickrPhoto.h"
```

(3) Then I define a property to hold the object, in the @interface section:

```
@property (weak, nonatomic) Flickr *flickr;
```

(4) In viewDidLoad, I allocate a new instance of the object:

```
self.flickr = [[Flickr alloc] init];
```

(5) Then in a later method, I call one of the methods in the API:

```
[self.flickr searchFlickrForTerm:textField.text completionBlock:^(...) { ... }];
```

However, the method is not getting called: I have put a NSLog line right before this method call, and it prints to console. I also put an NSLog in the first line of the method:

```
- (void)searchFlickrForTerm:(...) term completionBlock: ...
```

and it is not printing anything.

Why is this method not being called???!!! Never had this problem before. Its really annoying.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try changing your property to be strong instead of weak, and see if that fixes your issue:

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) Flickr *flickr;
```

If that fixes it, the issue was your property was being deallocated before you were able to use it.  You wouldn't see any error, because a "weak" property ensures that a pointer is set to nil once the object is deallocated (and Objective-C doesn't throw errors on sending messages to nil).